# How to use regular expressions to extract 3-tuple values from a string

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am trying to extract n 3-tuples (Si, Pi, Vi) from a string.

The string contains at least one such 3-tuple.
Pi and Vi are not mandatory.

```
SomeTextxyz@S1((property(P1)val(V1))@S2((property(P2)val(V2))@S3
           |----------1-------------|----------2-------------|-- n
```

The desired output would be:

```
Si,Pi,Vi.
```

So for n occurrences in the string the output should look like this:

```
[S1,P1,V1] [S2,P2,V2] ... [Sn-1,Pn-1,Vn-1] (without the brackets)
```

**Example**

The input string could be something like this:

```
MyCarGarage@Mustang((property(PS)val(500))@Porsche((property(PS)val(425‌​)).
```

Once processed the output should be:

```
Mustang,PS,500 Porsche,PS,425
```

Is there an efficient way to extract those 3-tuples using a regular expression 
(e.g. using C++ and `std::regex`) and what would it look like?

Comment: What's the expected output ?

Comment: would Pi,Vi always be within `()`

Comment: Yes, this would be mandatory. 
But ((property(Pi)val(Vi)) itself might be missing.

Comment: @diver_182 Maybe because I'm not familiar with C++, but I don't see "Si", "Pi", "Vi" in your input, so how come it's in the output ?

Comment: Si,Vi,Pi are indexed placeholders and refer to

[S1,V1,P1], [S2,V2,P2], ... [Sn-1,Vn-1,Pn-1] for n occurrences within the string.

Comment: @diver_182 Ok I think I got what you meant, [check it out](http://regex101.com/r/oF9lQ1) ...

Comment: It's not clear what you need to match. If it really is "S1,V1,P1" etc., then all you really need to extract is the number `n` since the rest is implied.

Comment: `@([^(@]+)(?:\(\(property\(([^)]+)\)val\(([^)]+)\)\))?` Something like this?  http://regexr.com?351cj

Comment: @Raymond:
The following example should clear this up.

MyCarGarage@Ford_Mustang((property(PS)val(500))@Porsche_911((property(PS)val(425)) should result in

Ford_Mustang,PS,500 
Porsche_911,PS,425

Comment: @diver_182 You mean like this http://regexr.com?351cm

Comment: Okay, you need to specify what you are actually parsing. Please explain in the question "S is everything between the `@` and the opening parenthesis. P is the string inside the parentheses that come after the word `property`. V is the string inside the parentheses that come after the word `val`." Actually, once you spell it out, the regular expression pretty much writes itself.

Comment: LOL we got from SPV to ford, porsche... That's a bad sign ...

Comment: @diver_182 you changed the rules that's why my regex is failing, my regex won't match `_` ...

Comment: You're right. I changed the example to stay "on track" ;)

Comment: Dude, you're using strange characters in `(425‌​)`, converting it into hex gives me `28343235E2808CE2808B29` which is totally not good ... Anyways here's a [regex](http://regex101.com/r/uP9cJ8) that will match the current requirements.

Comment: http://ideone.com/JelYjv  Granted, it could be done better, but I'm no C++ expert.  It's been a while since I did string manipulation in C or C++, so all that could be done better, but this is the basic concept, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/S7UQpA

I used C's `<regex.h>` instead of `std::regex` because `std::regex` isn't implemented in g++ (which is what IDEONE uses).  The regular expression I used:

```
"                        In C(++)? regexes are strings.
  @                      Literal match
  ([^(@]+)               As many non-@, non-( characters as possible.  This is group 1
  (                      Start another group (group 2)
    \\(\\(property\\(    Yet more literal matching
    ([^)]+)              As many non-) characters as possible.  Group 3.
    \\)val\\(            Literal again
    ([^)]+)              As many non-) characters as possible.  Group 4.
    \\)\\)               Literal parentheses
  )                      Close group 2
  ?                      Group 2 optional
"                        Close Regex
```

And some c++:

```
int getMatches(char* haystack, item** items){
```

first, calculate the length of the string (we'll use that later) and the number of `@` found in the string (the maximum number of matches)

```
    int l = -1, ats = 0;
    while (haystack[++l])
        if (haystack[l] == '@')
            ats++;
```

malloc a large enough array.

```
    *items = (item*) malloc(ats * sizeof(item));
    item* arr = *items;
```

Make a regex needle to find.  REGEX is `#define`d elsewhere.

```
    regex_t needle;
    regcomp(&needle, REGEX, REG_ICASE|REG_EXTENDED);
    regmatch_t match[5];
```

`ret` will hold the return value (0 for "found a match", but there are other errors you may want to be catching here).  `x` will be used to count the found matches.

```
    int ret;
    int x = -1;
```

Loop over matches (ret will be zero if a match is found).

```
    while (!(ret = regexec(&needle, haystack, 5, match,0))){
        ++x;
```

Get the name from match[1](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

```
        int bufsize = match[1].rm_eo-match[1].rm_so + 1;
        arr[x].name = (char *) malloc(bufsize);
        strncpy(arr[x].name, &(haystack[match[1].rm_so]), bufsize - 1);
        arr[x].name[bufsize-1]=0x0;
```

Check to make sure the property (match[3]) and the value (match[4]) were found.

```
        if (!(match[3].rm_so > l || match[3].rm_so<0 || match[3].rm_eo > l || match[3].rm_so< 0
                || match[4].rm_so > l || match[4].rm_so<0 || match[4].rm_eo > l || match[4].rm_so< 0)){
```

Get the property from match[3].

```
            bufsize = match[3].rm_eo-match[3].rm_so + 1;
            arr[x].property = (char *) malloc(bufsize);
            strncpy(arr[x].property, &(haystack[match[3].rm_so]), bufsize - 1);
            arr[x].property[bufsize-1]=0x0;
```

Get the value from match[4].

```
            bufsize = match[4].rm_eo-match[4].rm_so + 1;
            arr[x].value = (char *) malloc(bufsize);\
            strncpy(arr[x].value, &(haystack[match[4].rm_so]), bufsize - 1);
            arr[x].value[bufsize-1]=0x0;
        } else {
```

Otherwise, set both property and value to NULL.

```
            arr[x].property = NULL;
            arr[x].value = NULL;
        }
```

Move the haystack to past the match and decrement the known length.

```
        haystack = &(haystack[match[0].rm_eo]);
        l -= match[0].rm_eo;
    }
```

Return the number of matches.

```
    return x+1;
}
```

Hope this helps.  Though it occurs to me now that you never answered kind of a vital question:  [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

`@(.*?)\(\(property\((.*?)\)val\((.*?)\)\)` should do the trick.

example at http://regex101.com/r/bD1rY2

```
@                # Matches the @ symbol
(.*?)            # Captures everything until it encounters the next part (ungreedy wildcard)
\(\(property\(   # Matches the string "((property(" the backslashes escape the parenthesis
(.*?)            # Same as the one above
\)val\(          # Matches the string ")val(" 
(.*?)            # Same as the one above
\)\)             # Matches the string "))"
```

How you should implement this in C++ i don't know but that is the easy part :)

Comment: This won't match the case where there is no property/value pair.